# How to do something before and after action's execute method in Struts 1.3?

Tags: request, struts, struts-1

I want to do something say logging, before and after action class's execute method. I am using struts 1.3 . This is more like aspect programming.

I tried processPreprocess() of RequestProcessor by overriding it, but that is called before execute() only. Plus I want to access ActionMapping at both the places(before and after).

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should try filter to achieve your requirement. Create a Filter do mapping in `web.xml` and overide `doFilter` method like below code.

```
 public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,

       FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        beforeMethod(request,response);

        chain.doFilter(request, response);

        afterMethod(request,response);


    }
```

If filter is not applicable or fit in your requirement try below logic.

- Create an Action class, say `MyAction`, by extending `org.apache.struts.action.Action`.
- Create all other `Action classes` in your Web application by extending `MyAction`.

In `MyAction`, create a method `operate()`, as in

```
public abstract ActionForward operate(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException;
```

- In MyAction add one or more generic methods to the application, for example `before()`, `after()`.
- If all Action classes must implement this method, make it `abstract`.
- If some Action classes will provide a case-specific implementation, declare the method protected and give it a default implementation.

In MyAction override execute methode like below code

```
public ActionForward execute (ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException
 {

           before();

           ActionForward forward = operate(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)

           after();

           return forward ;

}
```

Comment: I thought of it, but I need access to ActionMapping at before and after. We can get it from request with getParamter("Globals.MAPPING_KEY")but that is added in RequestProcessor only. At filters this is not available.

Comment: If you have any doubt in understanding above code do comment here.

Comment: This is good idea. But we don't want to write any wrappers. Thank you though.

Comment: @RaisAlam I know this is a long shot but you seem to be very knowledgeable on the subject and I was wondering if you wouldn't mind taking a look at an issue im having? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43072965/servletactioncontext-getaction-method-returns-null/43073188?noredirect=1#comment73231139_43073188