# ServletActionContext getAction method returns null

Tags: java, struts-1

I am using a servlet filter where I am trying to get the action associated with the current request.

Relevant sections of my filter:

```
private ServletContext context;

public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
    this.context = config.getServletContext();
}

protected void doFilter(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    ServletActionContext actionContext = new ServletActionContext(context, request, response);

    Action action = actionContext.getAction();
    // action == null

}
```

My problem is that `action` ends up being null. Both of the context variables get populated with a value, but for some reason it cant find the action. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: What is your requirement if you paste your requirement we can discuss alternative methods

Comment: I was trying to use Annotations in some of my action classes to mark them as requiring a certain access level, and then checking for the existence of that annotation when the action passes through the filter. Currently I am keeping a list of the protected paths in my filter, and then using the request object to compare the path against the list to see if it required an access check.

Comment: Seems interesting and very useful and big architecture requirement, But friend frankly speaking this not a place where we can write full architecture level code. Here we can discuss very basic problems. But your requirement need full architecture level code which not possible here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ServletActionContext are initialised and all required variable are filled properly when control pass through ActionServlet.

Filter are executed before ActionServlet and and Creating object in filter method doesnt set Action

That is the main reason because of that some getter method of ServletActionContext returns null values because it doesn't gone through ActionServlet and hence all properties are not initialised.

Comment: This makes sense! Thank you for explaining it so well.